# Expanding Universe Balloon Analogy - Anything Similar for Time?

Tags: cosmology, time, universe, space-expansion

It is difficult to imagine the infiniteness of space and how it itself is expanding rather than the universe expanding into something else.  A helpful analogy is that of drawing little dots (representing galaxies or some other sub-universal structure) onto a deflated balloon and then blowing it up.  The surface expands in all directions, with each dot moving away from every other dot.  Although the analogous surface (the outside of the balloon) is effectively 2 dimensional, it's possible to imagine its translation into 3 dimensions.

As for time, though, I have a hard time picturing its "before / during / after" states, and I realize those words aren't even accurate.  Time supposedly began at the Big Bang and may end at the Big Crunch.  But I'm wondering if anyone knows of an analogy for time, similar to the balloon analogy that applies to space.  Is there a way to imagine time in some comprehensible way?

Comment: At physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251088/… , John Duffield's answer explains exactly how the balloon analogy is imperfect (what with a balloon's surface not being, if you stop to think about it, a perfect sphere...).

Comment: At https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GwzN5YwMzv0 , the physicist Sabine Hossenfelder provides some graphical info about the relation between space and time.  On cosmological scales, it's easily confused because of subtle differences between 1905's Special Relativity & the later remainder of General Relativity:  These differences are discussed in many articles by Davis & Lineweaver, all of which contain the phrase "expanding confusion".

Answer (score -1):

time will disappear in the same way it appears I don't know how to explain it  but in easy way the the end is just the beginning  and it will look like a cycle as it began it will end

Comment: I became moslem  for that analysis of this problem it had  explanation for this one

Comment: Can you please provide some reasoning?

Comment: blowing In a balon had 2 parts  1th  was blowing but not with power just to fill the empty space  that happen in the early moments after big bang ... 2th it is to use power to expand that balloon so it can reach to a point that if you  put more force it won't be able to contain that amount and it will explode to bring them balon back to it normal shape and that what is going to happen in our universe it will reach a point that it will crash into each other .. Big crash..  and that will let all the force